# Send data GET lost data with hashmark#

Tags: php

When I send data but there is hashmark #, the data behind is lost, how can I solve the problem

For example:

```
<?php
$tk = 'xhnaut';
$mk = 'i4kj.JbnAA7#';
$api = '28191';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_URL => $link.'?tt=1&user='.$tk.'&pass='.$mk.'&api='.$api,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'by to9xvn',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, 
));
?>
```

When I send data but there is hashmark #, the data behind is lost, how can I solve the problem

Comment: Each of your variables in the query string should be run through `urlencode`, or use `http_build_query` to generate it (which will handle the urlencoding for you).

Comment: (Also, passwords in a URL? Noooooo.)